# Suppress display of final frame of animation in jupyter

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook, matplotlib-animation

I am working on a project that involves generating a `matplotlib` animation using `pyplot.imshow` for the frames. I am doing this in a `jupyter` notebook. I have managed to get it working, but there is one annoying bug (or feature?) left. After the animation is created, `Jupyter` shows the last frame of the animation in the output cell. I would like the output to include the animation, captured as html, but not this final frame.  Here is a simple example:

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import animation
from IPython.display import HTML

grid = np.zeros((10,10),dtype=int)
fig1 = plt.figure(figsize=(8,8))

ax1 = fig1.add_subplot(1,1,1)
def animate(i):
    grid[i,i]=1
    ax1.imshow(grid)
    return 
ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig1, animate,frames=10);

html = HTML(ani.to_jshtml())
display(html)
```

I can use the `capture magic`, but that suppresses everything. This would be OK, but my final goal is to make this public, via binder, and make it as simple as possible for students to use.

I have seen `matplotlib` animations on the web that don't seem to have this problems, but those used plot, rather than `imshow`, which might be an issue.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's the answer I got from the same thing I was looking for in 'jupyter lab'. Just add `plt.close()`.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import animation
from IPython.display import HTML

grid = np.zeros((10,10),dtype=int)
fig1 = plt.figure(figsize=(8,8))

ax1 = fig1.add_subplot(1,1,1)
def animate(i):
    grid[i,i]=1
    ax1.imshow(grid)
    return 
ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig1, animate,frames=10);

html = HTML(ani.to_jshtml())
display(html)
plt.close() # update
```

Comment: Thanks very much! plt.close() is just what I needed.